# How can I use storyboard iOS to layout both the portrait and landscape orientations of a single view?

Tags: ios, xcode4, storyboard, landscape-portrait

I want to minimize the amount of code I have to write, and use storyboards in xcode to specify the way the view should appear when in both portrait and landscape views.

What is the best/recommended way to do this that minimizes code? I've done some research, but am having trouble finding a simple solution..is it necessary to do some conditional segues, and re-hook up everything in my landscape view, or is there a simpler solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you define the autoResizingMask (or go to the size inspector in Interface Builder, as shown below) so that the controls will move or resize as the screen size changes. If you do that, you'll generally have pretty decent support for both landscape and portrait. You'll only have to do programmatic changes to the controls' frames if you do some fairly significant changes on orientation changes (e.g. you want to shuffle the various controls around so that they are in very different positions with respect to each other when you change orientation or you want to load very different UIImages). But 90% of the time, autoresizing settings can handle simple moving/resizing/recentering of controls for you:

[image: autoResizing mask options in Interface Builder]